# Team social network, with collaborative inline PDF commenting

Tags: file-management, collaboration, chat, social-networks, communication

My small business (<20 employees) is looking for an internal social network platform to replace [**Yammer**](http://yammer.com).

Yammer recently binned its inline PDF commenting system, which we used a lot to group proof documents and content before publishing and releasing.

We also used it for general socialising and information sharing, within our teams and with the office at large.

We've looked at **Slack** and **HipChat** amongst others, but from what I can tell, none of them offer an easy way to share files and collaboratively inline comment on PDFs (and ideally other files like images).

**So: team social network platform suggestions please. Ideally is:**

- file commenting capable **(very important, not found one with this)**
- online / in cloud
- available on mobile & desktop
- configurable group chats
- personal messaging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: We ended up going with [Convo](https://www.convo.com/) for its fairly decent pricing structure, and the fact that they've been putting a lot of work into revamping the service recently.

Answer (score 1):

Free is [BlaBlanet](https://github.com/BlaBlaNet/BlaBlaNet) you can upload files and pictures and comment can be install us private social network. The theme work in a Mobile Phone you can have online in your server or in cloud . They have conversejs addon can be setup with your own xmpp server that means you have groups chat personal messaging.Ldap Caldav and Carddav support

Difficulty medium you need a basic base for install and you need a valid ssl certificate